# C++ Measure Display String Width (alternative to c# TextRenderer.MeasureText)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to get the actual display width of a string. I used `GetTextExtentPoint32` and it gives me the width properly if I am using a mono space font. If the font is not set to a mono space font or if the font doesn't support a particular language character, it is returning `font size * string length`. That is if the font size is set to 16 and the string length is 5, then it will return 16 * 5 = 80.

Is there a way to get the actual Display String Width?
In C# I am able to do this with TextRenderer.MeasureText.

Comment: You can try [DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) with the DT_CALCRECT flag.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I used the DrawText. It worked properly to calculate the width of the text. But is is causing performance issue in my application. Is there any other option to do this?